# AWS S3 cannot upload file with spring boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file-upload

when i do a post request i gave following logs.

```
2020-11-15 16:44:31.568  INFO 22872 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.aws.awss3.serviceimpl.AmazonClient   : Caught an AmazonServiceException from GET requests, rejected reasons:
2020-11-15 16:44:31.568  INFO 22872 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.aws.awss3.serviceimpl.AmazonClient   : Error Message:    Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: ********** ; S3 Extended Request ID: YMIe4OqTzt0f84HP4L8S0mjpuL2RL25bV/mqyK5iX0+M9lKjDdn/Q1sBfjwd2scCu9BOUxoPqkM=; Proxy: null)
2020-11-15 16:44:31.568  INFO 22872 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.aws.awss3.serviceimpl.AmazonClient   : HTTP Status Code: 403
2020-11-15 16:44:31.568  INFO 22872 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.aws.awss3.serviceimpl.AmazonClient   : AWS Error Code:   AccessDenied
2020-11-15 16:44:31.568  INFO 22872 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.aws.awss3.serviceimpl.AmazonClient   : Error Type:       Client
2020-11-15 16:44:31.569  INFO 22872 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.aws.awss3.serviceimpl.AmazonClient   : Request ID:       ############
```

Comment: The error 403 is well known "Forbidden". You don't have bucket permissions or you have not initialised properly the credentials for the SDK AWS client.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty self explanatory. You don't have the correct permissions to access / update the S3 bucket. Check the S3 bucket policy / configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your IAM role. You should be provided with s3 write access to proceed